# Pronunciation of HOMFLY polynomial

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants, pronunciation

How should HOMFLY polynomial be pronounced? It is an acronym, but clearly chosen so that it could be pronounced as a word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every knot theorist I know says "HOM-flee."  Potentially more correct is "HOM-flee PEE TEE" (for HOMFLY-PT) to recognize the independent work of Przytycki and Traczyk.

Comment: and I thought it was pronounced like "home-fly" ! (`/həʊm-flaɪ/`)